# Lodash or best approach to combining two arrays of objects with matching key

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

Working with *google-map-react* heat map. I need to create a new array of objects from two api responses without that key:value used to compare the arrays

```
let arr1 = [
  {"db_area":"1", "lat":"42.010531", "lng":"-87.670748"},
  {"db_area":"2", "lat":"42.001567", "lng":"-87.695137"},
  {"db_area":"3", "lat":"41.966063", "lng":"-87.656105"}
]

let arr2 = [
  {"comm_area":"1", "weight":"200"},
  {"comm_area":"2", "weight":"125"},
  {"comm_area":"3", "weight":"33"}
]

result = [
  {"lat":"42.010531", "lng":"-87.670748", "weight":"200"},
  {"lat":"42.001567", "lng":"-87.695137", "weight":"125"},
  {"lat":"41.966063", "lng":"-87.656105", "weight":"33"}
]
```

I tried to loop booth arrays, and it formatted correctly, but it created an array which the total length was the total of both arrays

```
const mergedandfilterd = [];

const result = mergedandfiltered;

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++)
    {
        if (obj1[i]['db_area'] == arr2[j]['comm_area'])
        {
            mergedandfiltered.push({
                "lat": arr1[i]['lat'],
                "lng": arr1[i]['lng'],
                "weight": arr2[j]['weight']
            });

            console.log(mergedandfiltered);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is both the arrays are always sorted ? always will have same `db_Area` and `comm_area` ?

Comment: I believe so. But cant guarantee since arr2 is coming from a public API. But comm_area and db_area match. So the lat and lng of db_area=1 are the gecoordinates for comm_area=1

Comment: So the array1 will always be sorted ? You want the order to be same as array1 or array2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (`weightMap`) from the `arr2`, then you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `arr1` to generate your desired result:

```js
let arr1 = [
  {"db_area":"1", "lat":"42.010531", "lng":"-87.670748"},
  {"db_area":"2", "lat":"42.001567", "lng":"-87.695137"},
  {"db_area":"3", "lat":"41.966063", "lng":"-87.656105"}
];

let arr2 = [
  {"comm_area":"1", "weight":"200"},
  {"comm_area":"2", "weight":"125"},
  {"comm_area":"3", "weight":"33"}
];

let weightMap = new Map(arr2.map(({comm_area, weight}) => [comm_area, weight]));

let res = arr1.map(
  ({db_area, lat, lng}) => ({lat, lng, weight: weightMap.get(db_area)})
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `map`, considering both the arrays have same amount of elements and also sorted

```js
let arr1 = [{"db_area":"1", "lat":"42.010531", "lng":"-87.670748"},{"db_area":"2", "lat":"42.001567", "lng":"-87.695137"},{"db_area":"3", "lat":"41.966063", "lng":"-87.656105"}]
let arr2 = [{"comm_area":"1", "weight":"200"},{"comm_area":"2", "weight":"125"},{"comm_area":"3", "weight":"33"}]

let final = arr1.map(({lat,lng},index)=>{
  let {weight} = arr2[index]
  return {lat,lng,weight}
})
    
console.log(final)
```

Note:-  If not sorted by default always than you can first sort and than use above map

```
arr.sort((a,b)=> a.propertyName - b.propertyName )
```

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary of either one of the array and with `reduce` you can create your output array.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    "db_area": "1",
    "lat": "42.010531",
    "lng": "-87.670748"
  },
  {
    "db_area": "2",
    "lat": "42.001567",
    "lng": "-87.695137"
  },
  {
    "db_area": "3",
    "lat": "41.966063",
    "lng": "-87.656105"
  }
]

const arr2 = [{
    "comm_area": "1",
    "weight": "200"
  },
  {
    "comm_area": "2",
    "weight": "125"
  },
  {
    "comm_area": "3",
    "weight": "33"
  }
]

// create a dictionary from array
function toDictionary(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce((dict, obj) => {
    dict[obj[key]] = obj;
    return dict;
  }, {});
}

// creating dictionary to avoid inner loop - if we are not creating a dictionary, we endup looping through the array for each element in another arrray just to find the match. Note: accessing value from a dictionary is alway O(1)
const dict = toDictionary(arr1, 'db_area'); // {1: {"db_area": "1", "lat": "42.010531", "lng": "-87.670748" }....}

// merge logic
const result = arr2
  .reduce((output, obj) => {
  // only push the object if db_area and comm_area matches
    if(dict[obj.comm_area]) {
      const {
        lat,
        lng
      } = dict[obj.comm_area];
      output.push({lat, lng, weight: obj.weight});
    }
    
    return output;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, you can merge objects with whatever properties they have and only remove the ID keys:

```
const keys = ["comm_area", "db_area"]
arr1ByDbArea = _(arr1).keyBy("db_area")
result = arr2.map(o => _.omit({...o, ...arr1ByDbArea.get(o.comm_area)}, keys));
```